# MATCH prior to MERGE in single Cypher query confuses ON MATCH and ON CREATE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've run into this on Neo4j 2.1.5. I have a query which I'm issuing from Node.js using the Neo4j REST API. The point of this query is to be able to create or update a given Node and set its state (including labels and properties) to some known state. The MATCH and REMOVE clause prior to the WITH is to work around the fact that there's no direct way to remove all of a Node's labels nor is there a way to update a Node's labels with a given set of labels. You have to explicitly remove the labels you don't want and add the labels you do want. And there's no way to remove labels in the MERGE clause.

A somewhat simplified version of the query looks like:

```
MATCH (m {name:'Brian'}) 
REMOVE m:l1:l2 
WITH m 
MERGE (n {name:'Brian'}) 
ON MATCH SET n={mprops} ON CREATE SET n={cprops} 
RETURN n
```

where `mprops = {updated:true, created:false}` and `cprops = {updated:false, created:true}`. I do this so that in a single Cypher query I can remove all of the Node's existing labels and set new labels using the ON MATCH clause.  The problem is that including the initial MATCH seems to confuse the ON MATCH vs ON CREATE logic.

Assuming the Brian Node already exists, the result of this query should show that n.created = false and n.updated = true. However, I get the opposite result, n.created=true, n.updated=false.  If I remove the initial MATCH (and WITH) clause and execute only the MERGE clause, the results are as expected. So somehow, the inclusion of the MATCH clause causes the MERGE clause to think that a CREATE vs MATCH is happening.

I realize this is a weird use of the WITH clause, but it did seem like it would work around the limitation in manipulating labels. And Cypher thinks that it's valid Cypher.  I'm assuming this is just a bug and an edge case, but I wanted to get others insights and possible alternatives before I report it.

I realize that I could have created a transaction and issued the MATCH and MERGE as separate queries within that transaction, but there are reasons that this does not work well in the design of the API I'm writing.

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to understand this query, and I think some things are missing, in particular why isn't the `m` from `WITH m` being used in the below MERGE?  And I'm assuming `mprops` and `cprops` are passed in as variable bindings?   From your setup and description, I honestly can't tell why you're doing this as one query and not two.  The second query doesn't seem to depend on the first in any way, but you point out that the first query is messing up the second.  What API design issue prevents you from issuing multiple queries?

Comment: In addition, in your example, the MERGE would only be executed if the MATCH succeeded, so this should be an equivalent query:

      MATCH (m {name:'Brian'}) 
      REMOVE m:l1:l2
      SET m={mprops}
      RETURN m

Comment: I've added answer based on my prior comment.

Comment: I'm trying to add create-or-update logic as part of a wrapper API around Cypher that I'm writing. The createOrUpdate() method wants to set the state of a new Node or update the state of an existing node including the labels. So I needed a way to remove all of the labels so that the MERGE could replace them with new labels. The only purpose of the MATCH query is to remove the labels.  This is why the merge query doesn't do anything with the 'm' binding.  I wasn't aware that the MERGE would be executed only if the MATCH succeeded, so this doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I don't want to issue multiple queries (requiring multiple REST requests) for obvious performance reasons. I don't want to include multiple queries using the REST transaction endpoint because my wrapper API provides the option to create a transaction and include multiple wrapper API queries within that transaction.  This doesn't work if the createOrUpdate() method itself creates a transaction.  This is why I'm struggling to find a way to update the state of a Node in a single Cypher query.

Comment: Also you should always match and merge on :Label and property !! Otherwise for larger databases Neo4j has to scan the whole db.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefix your query with MATCH it will never execute if there is no existing ('Brian') node.

You also override all properties with your `SET n = {param}` you should use  `SET n += {param}`

```
MERGE (n:Label { name:'Brian' })
ON MATCH  SET n += {create :false,update:true }
ON CREATE SET n += {create :true,update:false }
REMOVE n:WrongLabel
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why your query would not work, but the issues brought up by @FrobberOfBits are valid.

However, logically, your example query is equivalent to this one:

```
  MATCH (m {name:'Brian'}) 
  REMOVE m:l1:l2
  SET m={mprops}
  RETURN m
```

This query is simpler, avoids the use of MERGE entirely, and may avoid whatever issue you are seeing. Does this represent what you were trying to do?

Comment: This implements the "update" part of the logic, but not the "create". In my wrapper API all Nodes have unique IDs (GUIDs).  You can call Node.save() on an in-memory representation of a Node.  If the Node does not have a GUID, then I just do a CREATE.  If the Node does have a GUID, then it *might* be an update to an existing Node or it might be an import of a Node that was previously exported. In this case I either need to issue a query to determine whether a Node with that GUID exists (expensive) OR use the ON MATCH/CREATE functionality of MERGE (much better) (continued)

Comment: This works fine for properties, but not for labels. In my query (and @cybersam's) you see that you can set an explicit set of properties on a Node with SET m={mprops}, but you can't do the same for labels. If a Node "m" has "label1", then doing SET m:label2:label3 will result in a Node with labels "label1", "label2", "label3". IMHO, this is something that should be fixed in Cypher.  Until then, I'm trying to find an efficient workaround